My USB flash drive is corrupt and I can't format or mount it
The USB flash drive is a DataTraveler 104 32GB. I used to use it, but it has stopped working.
If you plug it in on Windows, it freezes the disk management and the file explorer.
On Debian, disks show the USB drive, but 2 things happen.
Right after I plug the USB drive this is what disks shows:

After some time, this appears:

I can't do anything on disks because an error occurs:
Error wiping device: Failed to open the device 'dev/sdb1' (udisks-error-quark, 0)

On gparted it doesn't appear.
On the terminal I tried some commands but nothing.
df doesn't show it.
root@debian:~# df
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             1688436       0   1688436   0% /dev
tmpfs             344892    1600    343292   1% /run
/dev/sda2      478096136 5628056 448108656   2% /
tmpfs            1724452       0   1724452   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120      12      5108   1% /run/lock
/dev/sda1         523244    5972    517272   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs             344888    2508    342380   1% /run/user/1000

lsblk -f shows it:
root@debian:~# lsblk -f
NAME   FSTYPE FSVER LABEL UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
sda                                                                           
├─sda1 vfat   FAT32       E773-A64C                             505.1M     1% /boot/efi
├─sda2 ext4   1.0         510ab128-c4c5-4d45-8ae2-b514cc1c845c  427.3G     1% /
└─sda3 swap   1           f82271ea-0975-44ec-bb25-3deb0ec114b9                [SWAP]
sdb                                                                           
└─sdb1

Mounting the device doesn't work because it gives an error that /dev/sdb or /dev/sdb1 doesn't exist such directory or file.
